# Scroll Controller is not listening to scroll in Flutter

Tags: flutter

Im trying to listen to scroll for lazy loading but im not getting any Listen values,I have used ListView.builder widget and have attached a scroll contoller (_controller) and have instantiated controller in initState() method, need help with the issue

```
class _FeedsState extends State<Feeds> {
  ScrollController _controller;
  int pageNumber = 1;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = new ScrollController();
    _controller.addListener(scrollListener);

    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      _controller.animateTo(
        0.0,
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 10),
        curve: Curves.easeOut,
      );
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(widget.feedDetails);
    return widget.feedDetails.length == 0
        ? PostSomething(
            isAdmin: widget.isAdmin,
          )
        : ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            controller: _controller,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Column(
                children: [
                  index == 0
                      ? PostSomething(
                          isAdmin: widget.isAdmin,
                          profilePic: widget.feedDetails[0]["profile_pic"])
                      : Container(),
                  (Posts(
                    index: index,
                    feedDetails: widget.feedDetails[index],
                    displayProfileNavigation: widget.displayProfileNavigation,
                  )),
                ],
              );
            },
            itemCount: widget.feedDetails.length,
          );
  }

  void scrollListener() {
    print("Scrolling");
    if (_controller.position.pixels == _controller.position.maxScrollExtent) {
      print("Coooool");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

make:   `shrinkWrap: false,`, this will enable your scrolling,

if this show unbounded height exception, then try

```
return Scaffold(
        body: Expanded(
        ListView.builder(....your code..
```

Comment: its showing unbounded height exception eventhough i add Scaffold as parent

Comment: put your ListView.builder into the Expanded widget. It will solve the unbounded height exception.

Comment: can you please check by removing PostSomething widgets, just your scrolling and scroll listener is working or not?

Comment: if it works, then your PostSomething() widget need to be wrap in expanded widget.

Comment: Problem Solved!shrinkWrap=false and Expanded/Flexible solves problem,Thank you

Comment: I have less than 15 reputation so cannot Upvote

Comment: then you can just accept the answer brother :)

Comment: You should only use Expanded widget in the children of Row,Column,Flex.. those are flexible widgets